# VLC UDP network stream does not work in Windows, but does in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I've got a udp stream (not accesible to the outside world) that VLC has able to play under Linux, but isn't able in Windows. Windows Firewall is turned off. In order to test the udp stream in VLC, I temporarily turned off the antivirus' (ESET Smart Security) firewall, and VLC still wouldn't playback the stream.

How could I investigate what might be blocking the playback of the stream? **What's different between Linux and Windows in this regard?** Should I inspect the packets in Wireshark, would it help - and if so, what should I exactly look for?

edit: I was pointed at the VLC's "Messages" function. So here are both Linux's and Windows' VLC messages:

**Windows**

```
main debug: adding item `udp://238.1.3.1:1234' ( udp://@238.1.3.1:1234 )
qt4 debug: Adding a new MRL to recent ones: udp://@238.1.3.1:1234
main debug: processing request item: udp://238.1.3.1:1234, node: null, skip: 0
main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
main debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on udp://238.1.3.1:1234
main debug: udp://238.1.3.1:1234 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'udp://238.1.3.1:1234'
main debug: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `udp://@238.1.3.1:1234' gives access `udp' demux `' path `@238.1.3.1:1234'
main debug: creating demux: access='udp' demux='' location='@238.1.3.1:1234' file='\\@238.1.3.1:1234'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "udp": 12 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access 'udp' location='@238.1.3.1:1234', path='\\@238.1.3.1:1234'
main debug: looking for access module matching "udp": 20 candidates
access_udp debug: opening server=:0 local=238.1.3.1:1234
main debug: net: opening 238.1.3.1 datagram port 1234
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
main debug: using access module "access_udp"
main debug: Using block method for AStream*
main debug: starting pre-buffering
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
```

**Linux**

```
main debug: adding item `udp://238.1.3.1:1234' ( udp://@238.1.3.1:1234 )
qt4 debug: Adding a new MRL to recent ones: udp://@238.1.3.1:1234
main debug: processing request item: udp://238.1.3.1:1234, node: null, skip: 0
main debug: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
main debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on udp://238.1.3.1:1234
main debug: udp://238.1.3.1:1234 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'udp://238.1.3.1:1234'
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
main debug: `udp://@238.1.3.1:1234' gives access `udp' demux `' path `@238.1.3.1:1234'
main debug: creating demux: access='udp' demux='' location='@238.1.3.1:1234' file='(null)'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "udp": 20 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access 'udp' location='@238.1.3.1:1234', path='(null)'
main debug: looking for access module matching "udp": 25 candidates
access_udp debug: opening server=:0 local=238.1.3.1:1234
main debug: net: opening 238.1.3.1 datagram port 1234
main debug: using access module "access_udp"
main debug: Using block method for AStream*
main debug: starting pre-buffering
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
main debug: received first data after 16 ms
main debug: prebuffering done 1316 bytes in 0s - 75 KiB/s
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 9 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 9 candidates
main debug: using stream_filter module "record"
main debug: creating demux: access='udp' demux='' location='@238.1.3.1:1234' file='(null)'
main debug: looking for demux module matching "any": 63 candidates
ts debug: pid[704] unknown
ts debug: pid[804] unknown
ts debug: pid[204] unknown
ts debug: pid[811] unknown
ts debug: pid[8041] unknown
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: PATCallBack called
ts debug: new PAT ts_id=1 version=4 current_next=1
ts debug: * number=1 pid=204
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: PMTCallBack called
ts debug: new PMT program number=1 version=14 pid_pcr=704
ts debug: * es pid=704 type=2 dr->i_tag=0x2
ts debug: * es pid=704 type=2 fcc=mpgv
main debug: selecting program id=1
ts debug: * es pid=804 type=3 dr->i_tag=0xa
ts debug: found language: est
ts debug: * es pid=804 type=3 fcc=mpga
ts debug: * es pid=811 type=3 dr->i_tag=0xa
ts debug: found language: nld
ts debug: * es pid=811 type=3 fcc=mpga
ts debug: * es pid=8041 type=6 dr->i_tag=0x45
ts debug: * es pid=8041 type=6 fcc=telx
access_udp warning: unimplemented query in control
main debug: using demux module "ts"
main debug: looking for decoder module matching "any": 39 candidates
avcodec debug: trying to use direct rendering
avcodec debug: allowing 4 thread(s) for decoding
avcodec debug: avcodec codec (MPEG-1/2 Video) started
avcodec debug: using slice thread mode with 4 threads
main debug: using decoder module "avcodec"
main debug: looking for packetizer module matching "any": 21 candidates
main debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_mpegvideo"
main debug: looking for decoder module matching "any": 39 candidates
main debug: using decoder module "mpeg_audio"
ts debug: DEMUX_SET_GROUP 0 (nil)
access_udp warning: unimplemented query in control
main debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/mint/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
main debug: no meta reader modules matched
main debug: `udp://@238.1.3.1:1234' successfully opened
ts warning: first packet for pid=704 cc=0xc
ts warning: first packet for pid=804 cc=0x7
main debug: Buffering 0%
ts warning: first packet for pid=8041 cc=0x3
main debug: Buffering 2%
main debug: Buffering 4%
main debug: Buffering 7%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
ts debug: pid[1] unknown
main debug: Buffering 9%
main debug: Buffering 12%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
main debug: Buffering 14%
main debug: Buffering 17%
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
main debug: Buffering 19%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
main debug: Buffering 22%
main debug: Buffering 25%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
main debug: Buffering 27%
main debug: Buffering 29%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
mpeg_audio debug: MPGA channels:2 samplerate:48000 bitrate:192
main debug: reusing audio output
pulse debug: using stereo channel map
pulse debug: changed buffer metrics: maxlength=4194304, tlength=46080, prebuf=0, minreq=15360
pulse debug: connected to sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
main debug: output 'f32l' 44100 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
main debug: looking for audio volume module matching "any": 2 candidates
main debug: using audio volume module "float_mixer"
main debug: input 'mpga' 48000 Hz Stereo frame=1152 samples/1161 bytes
main debug: looking for audio filter module matching "scaletempo": 14 candidates
pulse debug: base volume: 65536
pulse debug: changing sink 0: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)
scaletempo debug: format: 48000 rate, 2 nch, 4 bps, fl32
scaletempo debug: params: 30 stride, 0.200 overlap, 14 search
scaletempo debug: 1.000 scale, 1440.000 stride_in, 1440 stride_out, 1152 standing, 288 overlap, 672 search, 2400 queue, fl32 mode
main debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
main debug: conversion: 'mpga'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
main debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 12 candidates
main debug: no audio converter modules matched
main debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 12 candidates
mpgatofixed32 debug: mpga->f32l, bits per sample: 32
main debug: using audio converter module "mpgatofixed32"
main debug: conversion pipeline complete
main debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
main debug: conversion pipeline complete
main debug: looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 3 candidates
main debug: using audio resampler module "samplerate"
main debug: End of audio preroll
main debug: Buffering 32%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
main debug: Buffering 35%
main debug: Buffering 37%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
main debug: Buffering 39%
main debug: Buffering 42%
ts debug: PSINewTableCallBack: table 0x42(66) ext=0x1(1)
ts debug: libdvbpsi (SDT decoder): Table version 8, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: SDTCallBack called
ts debug: new SDT ts_id=1 version=8 current_next=1 network_id=65280
ts debug: * service id=1 eit schedule=0 present=0 running=4 free_ca=0
main debug: EsOutProgramMeta: number=1
main debug: Buffering 45%
main debug: Buffering 47%
main debug: Buffering 49%
main debug: Buffering 52%
main debug: Buffering 54%
main debug: Buffering 57%
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
main debug: Buffering 59%
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: waiting for sequence start
packetizer_mpegvideo debug: size 720x576 fps=25.000
main debug: Buffering 62%
main debug: Buffering 64%
main debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 2 candidates
freetype debug: Building font databases.
freetype debug: Took 0 microseconds
main debug: Buffering 67%
freetype debug: Using Serif Bold as font from file /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
freetype debug: using fontsize: 2
main debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
main debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "any": 55 candidates
swscale debug: 32x32 chroma: YUVA -> 16x16 chroma: RGBA with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
main debug: using video filter2 module "swscale"
main debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "any": 55 candidates
yuvp debug: YUVP to YUVA converter
main debug: using video filter2 module "yuvp"
main debug: Deinterlacing available
main debug: deinterlace 1, mode blend, is_needed 0
main debug: Opening vout display wrapper
main debug: looking for vout display module matching "any": 12 candidates
main debug: looking for vout window xid module matching "qt4,any": 4 candidates
qt4 debug: requesting video window...
qt4 debug: Video was requested 0, 0
main debug: using vout window xid module "qt4"
main debug: looking for inhibit module matching "any": 2 candidates
dbus_screensaver debug: found service org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver
main debug: using inhibit module "dbus_screensaver"
xcb_xv debug: connected to X11.0 server
xcb_xv debug: vendor : The X.Org Foundation
xcb_xv debug: version: 11501000
xcb_xv debug: using screen 0xc1
xcb_xv debug: using XVideo extension v2.2
xcb_xv debug: using adaptor Intel(R) Textured Video
xcb_xv debug: using port 110
xcb_xv debug: using image format 0x30323449
xcb_xv debug: using X11 visual ID 0x45 (depth: 24)
xcb_xv debug: using X11 window 0x02200000
xcb_xv debug: using X11 graphic context 0x02200002
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'fullscreen' 0
main debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 1024x576 window
main debug: using vout display module "xcb_xv"
main debug: original format sz 720x576, of (0,0), vsz 720x576, 4cc I420, sar 64:45, msk r0x0 g0x0 b0x0
main debug: Adding 'deinterlace' as static
main debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "deinterlace": 55 candidates
deinterlace debug: using blend deinterlace method
deinterlace debug: deinterlacing
main debug: using video filter2 module "deinterlace"
main debug: Filter 'deinterlace' (0x7fc414010128) appended to chain
main debug: removing module "freetype"
main debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 2 candidates
freetype debug: Building font databases.
freetype debug: Took 0 microseconds
freetype debug: Using Serif Bold as font from file /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
freetype debug: using fontsize: 2
main debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
avcodec warning: disabling direct rendering
xcb_xv debug: display is visible
main error: Failed to resize display
main debug: End of video preroll
main debug: Received first picture
main debug: Buffering 70%
main debug: looking for video blending module matching "any": 1 candidates
main debug: using video blending module "blend"
main debug: Detected interlaced video
main debug: deinterlace 1, mode blend, is_needed 1
main debug: Buffering 72%
main debug: Buffering 74%
main debug: Buffering 77%
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
main debug: Buffering 79%
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
main debug: Buffering 82%
main debug: Buffering 85%
main debug: Buffering 87%
main debug: Buffering 90%
main debug: Buffering 92%
main debug: Buffering 95%
main debug: Buffering 97%
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
main debug: Stream buffering done (1000 ms in 987 ms)
main debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
pulse debug: cannot synchronize start
pulse debug: deferring start (215949 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (191476 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (166847 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (141772 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (117170 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (92627 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (68116 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (43643 us)
pulse debug: deferring start (19177 us)
pulse warning: starting late (-5365 us)
pulse debug: started
main warning: playback way too early (-210155): playing silence
main debug: inserting 9267 zeroes
pulse debug: changing sink 0: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): Table version 4, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PAT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): Table version 14, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (PMT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
ts debug: libdvbpsi (SDT decoder): Table version 8, i_extension 1, section 0 up to 0, current 1
ts debug: libdvbpsi (SDT decoder): ignoring already decoded section 0
```

Comment: VLC in Linux and Windows are very similar in this regard.  I would suggest trying it with the Messages (Tools menu) window open and turning up the verbosity (`-v=2` should give similar results at the command line)

Comment: Edited the original post with messages.

Comment: The Windows stopping at "starting pre-buffering" typically means its not receiving any data.  Are your Linux and Windows machines on the same network?

Comment: @heavyd Yes, it's a same laptop (WiFi disabled) and logs above are produced on the laptop with Windows and liveUSB Linux. I can see that this isn't my specific issue, it seems to be wider (https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=365964&sid=1b518ddaa372be1944a34769de96ee93#p365964). But the solution given there did not help.

Comment: Umm... `283.1.3.1` is not a valid multicast/IP address.  Did you mean to use `238.1.3.1`?

Comment: @heavyd I obscured the IP so I could post here. Let's imagine it's `238.1.3.1` then :)

Answer (score 4):

Who would've thought that the solution is that simple. I mentioned [a link](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=366970#p366970) in the comment section that said to disable the wireless adapter - this did not help. Then I was googling by using the keywords: `"firewall" site:videolan.org` and came across [this topic](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=330286#p330286) where the user was asked if he has VMWare or VirtualBox installed. And this gave me an idea to disable the `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter` and now the udp stream is working.

Comment: Hmm... I bet if you specified the interface to bind to you could make it work without disabling interfaces.  Something like: `udp://<your IP>@238.1.3.1:1234`  Try that with the interfaces enabled.

Comment: @heavyd That's strange, it didn't work. It should though. Given that the format is this: `udp://[[<source address>]@[<bind address>][:<bind port>]]`. So I looked up my laptop's IP via `ipconfig` and used the udp address with the IP and VLC would stay silent.

Comment: for me the all other solutions did not worked, but this worked like a charm, thanks alot for the trick

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and the solution given by user3596479 is correct. But You don't have to disable all virtual adapters, only change the interface priority.

Go into your network adapter you want to set as primary. Click the properties page. From there, click on Internet Protocol Version 4 and go to Properties. From there, click Advanced to get the following window. Set interface priority to a low value, for example, 5. Your computer will use this network card as primary.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Solved the problem for me. Thanks!