# IP TV (Multicast) not working on one PC

Tags: multicast, iptv, igmp

I can receive IP TV via Multicast using my ZyXEL ARMOR Z1 router.
It works for my Surface Laptop and my mobile Device (LG G4) via WLAN without problems.

With my Desktop PC it doesn't, neither using WLAN or LAN.
Router WAN Multicast setting is set to: IGMPv1/v2.

Both my Laptop and my Desktop PC are using Windows 10, latest update.
I try out the connection using an m3u file in VLC from my provider Fiber7 (Switzerland).

What can I do to at least see where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it's rather simple.
On my Computer I had VirtualBox (same with VMware) isntalled. The Ethernet adapter of those caused the issue.

Solution found here:
[VLC UDP network stream does not work in Windows, but does in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/889007/vlc-udp-network-stream-does-not-work-in-windows-but-does-in-linux)